# converting MathML to ASCIIMathML

Tags: java, mathml

I'm using TinyMCE and the ASCIIMathML javascript library to provide equation editing capabilities on a web page.  It's easy to take the ASCIIMathML, convert it to MathML, and then render the equation with any of the wonderful MathML rendering libraries.

What I haven't been able to figure out (and maybe I'm just missing something) is how to go in the other direction MathML -> ASCIIMathML.  I need to be able to support editing of documents that we'll be importing that contain MathML.  Does such a library exist that converts in the other direction?  My website stack is built on Java, so a Java library would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a tool that will do exactly what you want (or even if it's possible in general... perhaps MathML is more expressive than ASCIIMathML?)

If you want to implement such a transformation tool yourself, you could start by working with [JEuclid's MathML parser](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sourceforge/jeuclid/parser/Parser.html). Once you've got the parsed representation of your equation, you can start outputting [ASCIIMathML syntax](http://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/mathml/asciimathsyntax.html) by traversing the MathML DOM objects.